# Multiple sources with % substition in makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to create a rule for each existing file `*.html`.  In order to create a simple html from each html file.

```
 #Makefile
 destination=dynamic/
 mysite: $(destination)%.html

 $(destination)%.html: source/%.html
          #exemple
          sed -e 's/<h1>/<h2>/' $< > $@
```

But I get the error :

```
 make:  *** No rule to target dynamic/%.html needed by `site'.  Stop.
```

I would like to make mysite rule depend upon each of the files in the dynamic directory.  And to re-make each of the files in dynamic directory each time the corresponding source file is modified.

Is it possible?

Thank for your help.

Comment: The mysite rule is wrong: it does not know, what to make. You need to list all output files. Make does have globbing and replace that you could use to create this list. Though it can lead to makefiles that have problems.

Comment: You say “I would like to make mysite rule depend upon each of the files in the dynamic directory.”, but there are no files in this directory, when you start. And also % does not work like that, it must match a % in the target.

Comment: The first part (make mysite rule depend upon each of the html files) is easy. But the second (re-make each of the html files each time a source file is modified) is unclear; when `source/foo.html` has been modified, should Make rebuild `dynamic/foo.html`, or *all* of the html files that already exist in `dynamic/`?

Comment: @Beta Means that each source/%.html correspond to one and only one dynamic/%.html file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
destination=dynamic/

# this makes a list of all html files in source/
SOURCES := $(wildcard source/*.html)

# this transforms SOURCES into a list of files that belong in dynamic/ 
DESTS := $(patsubst source/%.html,$(destination)%.html, $(SOURCES))

.PHONY: mysite # just to let Make know that mysite is not actually a file
mysite: $(DESTS)

$(destination)%.html: source/%.html
    sed -e 's/<h1>/<h2>/' $< > $@ or whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to execute bash script and place its standard output into variables.

```
#Makefile
my_variable=$(script myScript.sh) 

$(my_variable)%.transformed: $(my_variable)%.original
      sed -e 's/<h1>/<h2>/' $< > $@ or whatever
```